# Is it possible to place a UIToolbar below a UICollectionView without a UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a UICollectionViewController that contains a UICollectionView, and a UIToolbar. I would like to place the UIToolbar below the UICollectionView (at the bottom of the screen).

What I have now is the UICollectionView that goes all the way to the bottom of the screen and the UIToolbar placed on top of it in the zorder. In the picture below the collection view extends below the toolbar.

[image: Toolbar on top of a CollectionViewController]

I understand that I can do this [with a NavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746384/how-can-i-add-a-uitoolbar-to-a-uiviewcontroller), but I have also read that navigation controllers are for drill down behavior. I don't want that- the items in this toolbar do not necessarily change the view. Also it seems like the NavigationController would make my code more complicated than necessary.

Note, my UIToolbar is added programmatically. I have also tried adding it in the storyboard but I can't figure out how to place the toolbar in my view. This is my storyboard:

[image]

I cannot drag the toolbar into the view and when I run this the storyboard toolbar does not appear.

This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760467/how-can-i-pin-a-uitoolbar-to-the-bottom-of-the-screen-in-a-uiscrollview) makes it seem like the toolbar can be "snapped" to the correct position or the scrollview can be "re-sized", but I'm not seeing this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created a UICollectionViewController then the UICollectionView is the main view and as such you can't put things above of below it and that is why you can't drag the UIToolbar onto the view.

What you will need to do is create a UIViewController which conforms to the UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate protocols instead.  That will have a UIView as its main view and to that you can add a UICollectionView and a UIToolbar and position them as you want.  Don't forget to also link the data source and delegate of the UICollectionView to your UIViewController.

Comment: Thanks. I did this and it wasn't even as painful as it sounded.

Comment: Just FYI, I did find one issue with this approach. It seems that UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews is called *before* the embedded UICollectionView.layoutSubview method is called. Presumably the controller is only paying attention to its immediate view (although the function then seems to be poorly named) Since the collectionView has no UICollectionViewController its not clear where to capture this event.

Comment: Good point however what you can do is call UICollectionView.setNeedsLayout and UICollectionView.layoutIfNeeded in the UIViewController.viewDidLayoutSubviews to get the UICollectioView.layoutSubview to happen at that point instead.

Comment: OK I'll try it. I found the issue because I was centering the scroll view using UIScrollView.setContentOffset, and it wasn't working the way it did before. The bounds of the scroll view weren't set up at same time so I started fiddling around with different places to set the offset.